# Method does not exist or incorrect signature Database.executeBatch

Tags: salesforce

I am looking for help figuring out why this doesn't work.

I had to change the APEX class names on a project. I fixed all the errors but one.

```
Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void executeBatch(OriginalOpportunityAdSourceBatch, Integer) from the type Database at line 38 column 18
```

I don't understand the error as the only thing that changed was the class name.

function with error

```
public PageReference runAllOpps(){

        Database.executeBatch(new OriginalOpportunityAdSourceBatch(),batchSize);

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+opp.id);
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }
```

class it is calling

```
global class OriginalOpportunityAdSourceBatch {
  global Integer successCount = 0;
    global Integer errorCount = 0;
    global String errors = '';

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
                'Select id, AdSourceOriginalBucket__c, Ad_Source__c, isClosed, isWon from Opportunity WHERE IsClosed = TRUE AND IsWon = TRUE'
        );
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> scope){

        List<Database.SaveResult> srs = Database.update(OriginalOpportunityActions.ProcessAdSource(scope),false);

        for(Database.SaveResult sr:srs) {

            if(sr.isSuccess()) {
                successCount++;
            }
            else {
                errorCount++;
                errors += 'Opportunity Failed to Update. Record ID: ' + sr.getId();

                for(Database.Error er: sr.getErrors()) {
                    errors += er.message;
                }

                errors += '<br/>';
            }
        }

    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

        String emailBody = 'Successful Updates: ' + successCount + ' Error Count: ' + errorCount;
        if(errors!='') {
            emailBody += ' -- ' + errors;
        }
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{UserInfo.getUserEmail()});
        mail.setReplyTo(UserInfo.getUserEmail());
        mail.setSubject('Batch Original Opportunity Update Completed');
        mail.setHTMLBody(emailBody);
        system.debug('emailBody -- ' + emailBody);
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailmessage>{mail});}
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you made has start/execute/finish methods but you can change them at any time. You need to "promise" Salesforce they'll always be there.

You forgot to add`implements Database.Batchable<sObject>`to the class declaration. Fix it and then the code that uses this class should compile.